# GetTitle() Method of WebDriver is not working for Frame Tag Doc

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

I am trying to fetch  of Frame after switching but it is still returning Title of Main WebPage. Sharing code and DOM details of Frame:

```
    WebDriver driver  = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/the-magical-iframe-tag-an-introduction/");

    List<WebElement> IframaList=driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));

    System.out.println("total number of frame is "+IframaList.size());

    for(WebElement e : IframaList){
        System.out.println( e.getAttribute("name"));
    }

    driver.switchTo().frame("myDemoFrame");

    

    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Dom Structure :

[image: Dom Details with Title ttag]

**Note: I checked RemoteWebdriver Implementation of gettitle() and It says that It returns the title of Page. Does it mean the Title of the WebPage only?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function getTitle() only returns the top level Title

Refer to the document below for more info.

> This command returns the document title of the current top-level browsing context, equivalent to calling document.title.

https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/#get-title

Answer (score 0):

After switch to `<iframe>` you can get the title with following approach:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("myDemoFrame");
if(driver.findElements(By.tagName("title")).size()>0) {
    String currentTitle = driver.findElement(By.tagName("title")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
    System.out.println(currentTitle);
}
```

Comment: this is not going to help as We do not have. "innerText" @franH